# How to select list of records from a table for matching ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using .NET Core and Entity Framework. Here I am doing some validation to check before I make an entry to the table

```
public record MyMessage
{
    public IEnumerable<long?> mymsgIds
    public DateTime mydate
}
```

I have a table where I have list of records and need to select if any record contains the mymsgIds.
Here is the dbset

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? MsgId { get; set; }
}

var result = await _dbContext.MyTable.Where(c => c.MsgId.Contains(mymsgIds));
```

I get a message long doesnot contain definition for contains. Can I get some help to correct my query?

Comment: Whats the defination of your `MyTable` could you please include here?

Comment: You could try this `var allMyTableIds = await _context.MyTable.Select(x => x.MsgId).ToList();
   return mymsgIds.All(eachIds => allMyTableIds .Contains(eachIds));`

Comment: updated MyTable definition in my question

Comment: It will return you true or false if the ids exist. So do you want to pass all Ids you will get always last ids results. What do you want? Do you want to check all containing Ids status or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
var listOfIds = mymsgIds.ToList();
var result = await _dbContext.MyTable.Where(c => listOfIds.Contains(c.MsgId)).ToList();
```

Comment: IEnumerable<long> doesnt contain a definition for Contains is the error i recieve with this

Comment: you can make mymsgIds list then . mymsgIds.ToList().Contains(c.MsgId);

Answer (score 0):

> I get a message long doesnot contain definition for contains. Can I
> get some help to correct my query?

Well, it can be fixed in various way. When you would use Contains, the object you're looking for [must match the type List or T of the IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#definition). Therefore, you cannot search IEnumerable directly because MyTable is type of list and your mymsgIds is IEnumerable<long?> so it would through your exception.

You can try in following way:

Demo List:

```
IEnumerable<long> mymsgIds = new List<long>
            {
               1, 221, 3, 4055, 5, 6, 700
            };
```

**Way: 1 : When Check All mymsgIds Together**

```
    var allMyTableIds = _context.MyTable.Select(x => x.MsgId).ToList();

    //Check Each
    foreach (var eachIds in mymsgIds)
    {
        var isExist = allMyTableIds.Contains(eachIds);
    }
```

**Way: 2: When Check Only Single Id**

```
var checkIdStaus = _context.MyTable.Select(x => x.MsgId).ToList().Contains(mymsgIds.FirstOrDefault());
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table where I have list of records and need to select if any record contains the mymsgIds.

This is not completely clear.

- I assume that a list of records means a list of `MyMessages`. I assume this list is in your local process.
- *need to select IF*? I assume you meant to say, that you need to select all `MyTable` objects that have a value for property `MsgId` that equals at least one of the values of property `MyMsgIds` that is in your sequence of `MyMessages`.

So first we need to have all `MyMsgIds` of all `MyMessages` in one sequence. We don't need duplicates.

```
List<MyMessage> myMessages = ...
IEnumerable<long> allNonNullMsgIds = myMessages
    .Where(message => message.MyMsgIds != null)
    .SelectMany(message => message.MyMsgIds)
    .Distinct();
```

In words: from all objects of class `MyMessage` in the list `myMessages`, keep only those MyMessages that have a non-null value of property MyMsgIds. From the remaining sequence of MyMessages, make one list of all values of MyMsgIds. Finally remove all duplicates.

Example:
myDate = 01-01-2023 MyMsgIds = {14, 23 }
myDate = 01-02-2023 MyMsgIds = null
myDate = 01-03-2023 MyMsgIds = {14, 18, 30}

```
allNonNullMsgIds = {14, 23, 18, 30}   // or in any other order
```

Now your want all MyTable objects that have a value for property MsgId that is in allNonNullMsgIds:

```
var result = dbContext.MyTable
    .Where(tableRow => tableRow.MsgId != null
                    && allNonNullMsgIds.Contains(tableRow.MsgId));
```

In words: from all rows in `MyTable`, keep only those rows that have a non-null value for property `MsgId` and that have a value for this property that is in sequence `allNonNullMsgIds`.